# Early bird discounts and ribbis

Tags: halacha, time, transactions, lending-interest-ribbis

Are early-bird discounts ribbis? For example, "buy before March 1, 10% off", or "tickets $12 in advance, $15 at the door"

Inspired by http://myparnasa.com/collecting-interest-ribbis/

Comment: Possible dups: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11572/are-magazine-subscriptions-ribbis and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11657/if-magazine-subscriptions-are-ribbis-are-bus-tokens-postage-stamps-and-other

Comment: I agree with the first one as a dup; I added a comment there, which will hopefully be indexed, as I wouldn't think to look for magazine subscriptions in the context of finding existing questions which address this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the writer who wrote post about Ribbis cited here.

I've since read the Artscroll book about Ribbis by Rabbi Reisman, and he says that Early-Bird discounts are usually considered Ribbis. Since it's d'rabbanan ribbis, there may be leniencies (e.g. for non-profits, corporations) but it's pretty complicated.

If you are planning to do an early bird discount or any other pricing strategy to gets people to pay sooner rather than later, read the book or ask a shayla.
Kol tuv and thanks for posting

Naomi Elbinger

http://myparnasa.com